# Example of a set that is not an event

Tags: probability-theory

I know that for uncountably infinite sample spaces, an event is a subset of the sample space, but not every set is an event. However, I'm coming up short when trying to actually find a set that cannot be an event.

I'm not too well versed in measure theory, so if the answer turns out to be "go pick up a measure theory textbook", I'm fine with that (edit: though I still wouldn't mind an answer that I can return to once I've understood the measure theory behind it).

Comment: Picking up a measure theory text would indeed be the right idea. The canonical example is :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set

Comment: To see this question from a completely different but insightful, or at least interesting, point of view, see chapters 15 (*Paradoxes of probability theory*) and B.4 (*Kronecker vs Waierstrass*) of  https://archive.org/details/XQUHIUXHIQUHIQXUIHX2 or https://www-biba.inrialpes.fr/Jaynes/prob.html

Comment: @pglpm I think the last part of your comment got cut off

Comment: It was, thank you. I edited it now.

Comment: Thanks :) Also, the last link yields a 404.

Comment: Can't type today! Here's the last link: http://www-biba.inrialpes.fr/Jaynes/prob.html

Comment: That works - thank you!